# Entity Framework Core: issue with Contains method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

There is my simplified model of db:

```
public class Chat
{
public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users {get; set;} //nav property - represents participants of a chat
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser // it represents a net-identity user; it does not have any references to chats
{...}
```

So, in controller's class I try to get chats such as contain current user as a participant:

```
var user = GetUser();
_context.Chats.Where(chat => chat.Users.Contains(user)).ToList();
```

This code throws exception:

> You can not use the type of expression ...ApplicationUser for
>   parameter's type 
>    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueBuffer" of method "Boolean
>    Contains[ValueBuffer](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueBuffer],
>    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueBuffer)"

What is the problem here?

Comment: Please provide a little more info regarding your controller code. What are you trying to assign it to?

Comment: The actual problem is that you are trying to compare objects ('user') as a hole. And since EF translates to SQL in the background, this will fail. There is no SQL function for compairing objects. Best you do a find by primary key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need use Any(), like this

```
 var chatsList =_context.Chats.Where(chat => chat.Users.Any(u => u.id== user.id)).ToList();
```